# To show a boundary around a specific color in a image using opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, colors

Actually i am working on color detection in python using opencv and I want to show a boundary around red color 
Here is my python code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

  _, frame = cap.read()
  frame=np.fliplr(frame)
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

  lower_red = np.array([0,170,175])
  upper_red = np.array([20,255,255])

  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
  res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
  kernel = np.ones((15,15),np.float32)/225
  smoothed = cv2.filter2D(res,-1,kernel)
  cv2.imshow('Original',frame)
  cv2.imshow('Averaging',smoothed)
  _, puck = cv2.threshold(smoothed, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  cv2.imshow('Puck',puck)
  k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
  if k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I am able to find the red color but i have some confusion to detect the position of the area where color is occurring.
Thanks

Comment: By *position of the area* you mean the pixel coordinates having red color?

Comment: Absolutely the position of red pixels

Comment: you can get that from `mask`. Every pixel that is not black meaning [0, 0, 0]

Comment: as mentioned `np.where()` can help in that matter !!

Comment: I like your idea of creating a boundary around the mask image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of coordinates using `numpy.where()` on `mask`. `mask` is a single channel image having [255] on regions with the red color and [0] on regions without it

```
indices = np.where(mask!= [0])
coordinates = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
```

- I used the numpy.where() method to retrieve a tuple indices of two arrays where the first array contains the x-coordinates of the white points and the second array contains the y-coordinates of the white pixels.

`indices` returns:

```
(array([375, 375, 375, ..., 915, 915, 915], dtype=int64),
 array([496, 497, 498, ..., 420, 421, 422], dtype=int64))
```

- I then used the `zip()` method to get a list of tuples containing those coordinates with the red color.

Printing coordinates gives me a list of coordinates having red color

Comment: Thanks @Jeru_Luke It helped so much. I wanna ask you one more thing ... is there any way to show a rectangle or circle around the particular red zone.

Comment: Yes indeed! For the particular mask image find contours using **cv2.findContours()**. Now contours will be found around regions having reddish pixels. You can draw bounding boxes around those contours using **cv2.boundingRect()**

Comment: Finally Got it ...Thanks : )